# Add item and bind command listview MVVM

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp, visual-studio-2017

I would make a listview, add item and bind a command from button in this listview in MVVM

How i can do that ?

I have created the listview in my View

View :

```
<Page
x:Class="mvvm_apple.Vue.MaListe"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:mvvm_apple.Vue"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
DataContext="{Binding CinqPageInstace, Source={StaticResource Locator}}" 
mc:Ignorable="d" Width="1280" Height="800">

<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Button Content="Retour" Command="{Binding RetourAuMenu}" Margin="41,45,0,722"/>
    <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="398" Margin="41,212,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1187"/>

</Grid>
```

ViewModel :

```
    private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public RelayCommand RetourAuMenu { get; private set; }

    public void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string str = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(str));
        }
    }

    public VM_MaListe(INavigationService navigationService)
    {

        _navigationService = navigationService;
        RetourAuMenu = new RelayCommand(_RetourAuMenu);
    }

    private void _RetourAuMenu()
    {
        // Do Something
        _navigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

I work with ViewModelLocator

Comment: You have to bind `ItemsSource` of the `ListView` to some kind of collection, preferably and `ObservableCollection`.

Comment: I have create a model : 
`public class MmaListe
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }`

ViewModel : 
      `private ObservableCollection<Modèle.MmaListe> items;

        public ObservableCollection<Modèle.MmaListe> Items
        {

            get
            {
                return items;
            }

            set
            {
                items = value;
            }

        } 

       public VM_MaListe(INavigationService navigationService)
        {            Items.Add(new Modèle.MmaListe { Name = "bonjour"});
      }
     `

Comment: View : 
           `
 <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"     HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="398" Margin="41,212,0,0"          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1187" Background="Azure">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Content="{Binding Name}" Command="{Binding       RetourAuMenu}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
                  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
             </ListView>      `

// I have my text but my Command doesn't work

Comment: Please update the question with that code so that it can be formatted. It's nearly impossible to read code posted as comments.